# Windows mobile 10: white text in option tags are invisible

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, windows-10-mobile

I have a styling for a selectbox with makes it dark background with white text:

```
select{
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

In the stock browser of Windows Phone 10 (Edge browser) if you open a select field you get, like in most other mobile browsers with input fields, a OS specific view of the `<option>` entries. The Edge Browser shows the select entries with white background, with the white text I use, the `<option>` entries are invisible. Does anyone know how to fix this?

What I tried:

```
select:focus::-ms-value{
   color: #000000; /* not working */
}

select::-ms-expand {
   color: #000000; /* not working */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edge on WP10 will respect the `color` property on an `option` selector so you can do this...

```
select {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;

  option: {
    color: #000000;
  }
}
```